# Trying to read each line of code separate from a file

Tags: java

I have the following information I am trying to read from a .txt file

> Griffey HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSH
>   Piazza OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHO
>   Pudge HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOP

I need to be able to separate the name, then each individual letter (preferably from something like a charAt. Each letter stands for a Hit, Out, Walk, Hit by Pitch, or Strikeout. I have to calculate each player's Batting Average, On Base Percentage, #Hits, #Walks, #Hit by Pitch. Finally I have to find the leaders of the 3 in each category.

So far, I am really stuck on being able to separate the names and plucking out each individual letter.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class readStats
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
//Pull stats.txt File
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");

//Create Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
//Read data from file
    while (input.hasNextLine()) 
    {
    String name1 = input.next();
    String griffey1 = input.nextLine();
    char batArray = griffey1.charAt(0);
    //char griffey2 = input.next().charAt(1);
    System.out.print(name1);
    //System.out.println(griffey1);
    //System.out.println(batArray[1]);
    }
}

}
```

My output is:

GriffeyPiazzaPudge

**UPDATE**

Okay I have variables for each "item" now with this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class readStats
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
//Pull stats.txt File
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");

//Create Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
//Read data from file
    while (input.hasNextLine()) 
    {
    String name1 = input.next();
    String stats1 = input.next();
    String name2 = input.next();
    String stats2 = input.next();
    String name3 = input.next();
    String stats3 = input.next();
    System.out.println(name1);
    System.out.println(stats1);
    System.out.println(name2);
    System.out.println(stats2);
    System.out.println(name3);
    System.out.println(stats3);
    }
}

}
```

**Output:**

Griffey

HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSH

Piazza

OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHO

Pudge

HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOP

Comment: Will you only ever have 3 lines of input data?

Comment: Yes for this exercise

Comment: Please review the answers below and mark one as correct.  Literally dozens of hours have been put into your question on the part of the SO coummunity.

Answer (score 1):

read each line then use

```
String words[ ] = String.split (" ");

words[0] = the name
words[1] = the code
```

then words[1] can then be split into a char array using

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

To read the lines do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while (input.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String line = input.nextLine();
    .
```

Comment: How do I separate the lines? When I call name1 from my program above it returns all 3 lines.

I think I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: Okay I have variables for each "item" now with code in update.

Comment: I just need to figure out to pull each letter from the strings from the stats1,2,3 strings so I can can manipulate each letter that stands for Hit, Walk, Out, Sacrifice, Strikeout, Hit by Pitch, etc.

Comment: Think about what data structure you want to end up with.  Do you want a count of each `letter` for each player, if so create that type of Structure (Think of `Map`)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class readStats
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("D:\\user\\Mahfuz\\stats.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = "";
String spliter = ",";
try {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] eachLise= line.split(spliter);
    String griffey1 =eachLise[1];
     for(int i=0; i<griffey1.length(); i++){
        char batArray = griffey1.charAt(i);
         System.out.println(batArray);
    }
}
}
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

txt file

```
Griffey,HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSH
Piazza,OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHO
Pudge,HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOP
```

OutPut

```
H
H
O
H
O
K
W
O
H
K
S
P
O
O
W
S
H
O
O
H
H
H
K
P
S
O
H
O
O
H
W
W
H
O
H
H
H
H
K
O
O
H
H
H
S
W
W
H
H
O
P
```

Comment: I have to have output like this written into another .txt file

 Individual stats – each item on a new line

o Name

o BA:<space><value>

o OB%:<space><value>

o H:<space><value>

o BB:<space><value>

o K:<space><value>

o HBP:<space><value>

o Blank line

 League leaders – each item on a new line

o League leaders header

o BA:<space><name list><space><value>

o OB%:<space><name list><space><value>

o H:<space><name list><space><value>

o BB:<space><name list><space><value>

o K:<space><name list><space><value>

o HBP:<space><name list><space><value>

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to get name:

> Note: Place stats.txt in same directory of class file

```
RegEx
^(\\w+)[^\\s]

|-- ^(\\w+) => starts with word one or more
|-- [^\\s] => not contain space character
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ReadStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Pull stats.txt File
            File file = new File("stats.txt");

            //Create Scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            //Read data from file
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)[^\\s]");
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.print(matcher.group());
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have this code now. This is helping me get each letter, but I'm wondering if there is any way to make a loop or something that would be faster/take up less lines?

```
import java.util.*;

public class readStats
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
//Pull stats.txt File
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");

//Create Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
//Read data from file
    while (input.hasNextLine()) 
    {
    String name1 = input.next();
    String stats1 = input.next();
    String name2 = input.next();
    String stats2 = input.next();
    String name3 = input.next();
    String stats3 = input.next();
    char OneABname1 = stats1.charAt(0);
    char TwoABname1 = stats1.charAt(1);
    System.out.println(name1);
    System.out.println(stats1);
    System.out.println(name2);
    System.out.println(stats2);
    System.out.println(name3);
    System.out.println(stats3);
    System.out.println(OneABname1);
    System.out.println(TwoABname1);
    }
}

}
```

**Output**

```
Griffey

HHOHOKWOHKSPOOWSH

Piazza

OOHHHKPSOHOOHWWHO

Pudge

HHHHKOOHHHSWWHHOP

H

H
```

My final output looks something like this written into another .txt file:

Individual stats – each item on a new line

Name

BA:

OB%:

H:

BB:

K:

HBP:

Blank line

League leaders – each item on a new line

League leaders header

BA:

OB%:

H:

BB:

K:

HBP:

Answer (score 0):

The following code parses each line of player stats, prints those stats to the console for each player, and then displays the leaders in each category.  As a few have mentioned already, a better long term solution might be to encapsulate the stats for each player into a class, and use a formal data structure such as a `Map`.

```
public class readStats {
    public static int getStat(String letter, String stats) {
        int count = stats.length() - stats.replace(letter, "").length();

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hitsLeader = null;
        String outsLeader = null;
        String walksLeader = null;
        String hitsByPitchLeader = null;
        String strikeoutsLeader = null;
        int maxHits = 0;
        int maxOuts = 0;
        int maxWalks = 0;
        int maxHitsByPitch = 0;
        int maxStrikeouts = 0;

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("stats.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] parts  = line.split(" ");
            int hits        = getStat("H", parts[1]);
            int outs        = getStat("O", parts[1]);
            int walks       = getStat("W", parts[1]);
            int hitsByPitch = getStat("P", parts[1]);
            int strikeouts  = getStat("S", parts[1]);
            double ba = (double)hits / parts[1].length();
            double obp = (double)(hits + walks + hitsByPitch) / parts[1].length();

            System.out.println("Player " + parts[0] + " has the following stats:");
            System.out.println("hits: " + hits);
            System.out.println("outs: " + outs);
            System.out.println("walks: " + walks);
            System.out.println("hits by pitch: " + hitsByPitch);
            System.out.println("strikeouts: " + strikeouts);
            System.out.println("batting average: " + ba);
            System.out.println("on base percentage: " + obp);

            if (hits > maxHits) {
                maxHits = hits;
                hitsLeader = parts[0];
            }

            if (outs > maxOuts) {
                maxOuts = outs;
                outsLeader = parts[0];
            }

            if (walks > maxWalks) {
                maxWalks = walks;
                walksLeader = parts[0];
            }

            if (hitsByPitch > maxHitsByPitch) {
                maxHitsByPitch = hitsByPitch;
                hitsByPitchLeader = parts[0];
            }

            if (strikeouts > maxStrikeouts) {
                maxHits = hits;
                strikeoutsLeader = parts[0];
            }
        }

        // print out leaders from all categories
        System.out.println("Leader in hits is: " + hitsLeader);
        System.out.println("Leader in outs is: " + outsLeader);
        System.out.println("Leader in walks is: " + walksLeader);
        System.out.println("Leader in hits by pitch is: " + hitsByPitchLeader);
        System.out.println("Leader in strikeouts is: " + strikeoutsLeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to have 3 separate classes (Ex. readStats,calcStats,printLeaders)

Comment: You don't need 3 classes to solve this problem, and I would not use such a solution.  In fact, I answered your question using one class.

Comment: Well, it's spitting out errors for me on line 19,29

int count = stats.length() - line.replace(letter, "").length();

 Strings [] parts = input.split(" ");

Comment: Sorry had a typo in there.  Try it again.  Use `int count = stats.length() - stats.replace(letter, "").length();`

Comment: Getting error on this:


Strings [] parts = input.split(" ");

Comment: Sorry again.  Use `String[] parts = input.split(" ");`  I didn't test this code, as you can tell, but the logic is sound I believe this is easiest way to get you running.

Comment: I also have to computer Batting Average and On Base percentage for each player. BA is Hits/Number of At Bats for each player and On Base Percentage is (hits + walks + hit by pitch) / plate appearances

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help. That fixed the line's problem, but it isn't liking the ints you have created for the categories.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can break each letter down individually, but I figured there is a much easier way to group everything.

Comment: I added on base percentage, but I'm not sure about batting average because I don't know how to compute the number of plate appearances from your stats.

Comment: Please mark as correct if it solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: total number of letters in the string with all of the letters are the at bats.

Comment: But then what is the number of plate appearances?

Comment: However many letters there are in the string. I think 17 in the case of this.

Comment: Please answer this directly: Are the number of at bats and the number of place appearances the same figure?

Comment: Yes. Also it is spitting back that it doesn't have a main class set? It also doesn't like the ints still.

Comment: I updated it again, it should be working now.  I had to make the helper method `static` because it is being called from the `static` `main()` method.

Comment: It's still not liking the String[] parts  = input.split(" "); line---------and the  int ba = hits / parts[1].length;

Comment: More compiler errors which I have just fixed.  Try again.

Comment: That works better, but Batting Average and OBP are getting 0. Im looking at why right now.

Comment: Change the type for these 2 stats to `double` and add a cast to the RHS.

Comment: Still coming up with 0 :( . I just found this too------- Walks, sacrifices and hit by pitches are not considered an at-bat

Comment: This is not a free homework service, sorry.  I won't make any further updates.

Comment: ?? You have helped greatly. Thank you! I wasn't treating this as a homework service.

Comment: How did you come up with the parts [1]? Im trying to understand so I can manipulate putting the batting average and on base percentage in?

Comment: `parts[1]` is the stats string (i.e. `OSWPO...`).  I already added the batting average.

Comment: Okay, im getting it now. I tried to add the sacrifices category, just like the other categories and it broke it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {              
                    //Pull stats.txt File
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("c:/stats.txt");
        //Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //Read data from file
            while (input.hasNextLine()) 
            {
            String name1 = input.next();
            String griffey1 = input.nextLine();


            char[] batArray = griffey1.trim().toCharArray();

            System.out.println(name1);
             System.out.println(griffey1);
            for(char c:batArray)
            {
                System.out.println(c);
            }              
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can parse out each player and build a bucket of each stat:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BaseballParser {

        class Player {
            String player;
            Map statCounts = new HashMap();

            public String toString() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Player: ").append(player).append("\n");
                for ( Character c : statCounts.keySet() ) {
                    sb.append(c).append(" : ").append(statCounts.get(c)).append("\n");
                }

                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

        public Map process(File file) throws Exception {
            if ( !file.exists() ) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot locate " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " for processing.");
            }

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            String nextLine;

            Map playerMap = new HashMap();

            while ( scanner.hasNext()  ){
                nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
                if ( nextLine.trim().length()  1 ) {
                System.out.println("Usage: BaseballParser [path to stats file]");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            BaseballParser parser = new BaseballParser();
            Map playerStats = parser.process(new File(s[0]));

            playerStats.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        }


    }
```

Outputs this:

```
Player: Piazza
P : 1
S : 1
W : 2
H : 6
K : 1
O : 6

Player: Pudge
P : 1
S : 1
W : 2
H : 9
K : 1
O : 3

Player: Griffey
P : 1
S : 2
W : 2
H : 5
K : 2
O : 5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain how you solved the problem, rather than just solving it. Also, in the future, avoid answering questions that ask for code with little or no effort towards writing it themselves.

Comment: Well... I didn't really solve his problem, just a piece of it. To be fair, OP did post some code prior to my post.